# Retroactively allocating key ranges in appengine

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I've got about 1.5M entities in my datastore. Because of a lack of understanding on my part, some of those entities have ids that I generated myself according to an algorithm that I wrote, and others have ids that were automatically allocated by the datastore.  I understand now that this could eventually cause a conflict, since the id allocator doesn't know about the ids I generated myself.

So.  Now I want to save those entities with my ids from being overwritten by accident later.  Can I just troll through every single entity I have and use allocateKeyRange for its id? I stopped generating my own ids a long time ago - there are just a few entities in danger - but I don't know which ones.  What's the best way to save my at-risk entities?

Edit: I should note that I do store references to ids in other entities, so it will be difficult to change the id of entities without lots of cascading lookups.

Comment: Do you store any Entity reference or Key in your properties?

Comment: Do you have multiple entities referencing the same entity key?

Comment: Yes, I do - it's sort of a file-system-like structure.

Comment: Can you include a string representation of an entity with an id generated by you, and a string representation of an entity with an autogenerated id ?

Comment: There's no difference in the structure of the entities. `{"id":1000, "message":"this was autogenerated!"}` and `{"id":1001, "message":"I set this id by hand without allocating it :("}`

Comment: I was wondering if one could spot a difference in the id range.

Comment: There's definitely a difference in the id range - the ids I generated are about 10,000,000 times bigger than the place where the auto-allocator seems to be.  I suppose I could just allocate a huge id range, from 0 to my largest id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, if the id range is different you should be able to use [DatastoreService.allocateIdRange](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/DatastoreService.html#allocateIdRange%28com.google.appengine.api.datastore.KeyRange%29) in order to reserve the ids that you already assigned to your entities manually.